# Haskell SplitOneOf definition issues

Tags: haskell

Hello Guys :D back with another Haskell question here. So I'm practicing for my final exam and I was doing an exercise from past exams and it's basically making the function splitOneOf if I'm not mistaken, I wish to create a function that upon detecting one of a given list of characters removes them from another list and returns a list of strings, from where it split.

What I have so far, which is not much since it doesn't work, is this

```
sep :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
sep _ [] = []
sep n xs
    | n `elem` xs = ... (I had stuff in here, didn't put for sake of it being easier to understand where I'm at trouble)
    | otherwise = error "Error"
```

What I want as a result would be this:

```
ghci> sep " \t\n" "As armas\te\tos barões\n   que"
    **> ["As","armas","e","os","barões","que"]
```

EDIT: After testing out the help you gave me, it's giving me an error, this is what I have:

```
sep :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
sep _ [] = []
sep n (x:xs) 
    | x `elem` n = " " ++ sep n xs
    | otherwise  = x : sep n xs
```

And it's giving me the following error:

```
Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[a]'
  Expected type: [[a]]
    Actual type: [Char]
  In the expression: " " ++ sep n xs

Couldn't match type '[a]' with 'Char'
  Expected type: [Char]
    Actual type: [[a]]
In the second argument of ´(++)´, namely ´sep n xs´
```

Comment: So using `splitOn` from `Data.List.Split` is not allowed?

Comment: @RoadRunner nope, only Prelude

Comment: Hint: take a look at the implementation of `splitOn`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have, it uses functions from Data.List and I may only use Prelude functions

Comment: @RoadRunner wouldn't that make it [[a]] then? Since "" is a list, [""] would be a list of lists am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are comparing lists or in this case as i understand we compare strings, there are a few things we need to understand. We can't check if something of type `[a]` is an element of some other type `[a]`. We can compare them, but we can never compare the elements by forcing an entire list upon another.

```
[a] `elem` [a] // makes no sense
 a  `elem` [a] // is what we are looking for.
```

To clean up a string is easy, one way is to replace all elements which holds for some kind of requirement with something else. In this case we could replace all the elements with a space, and we can apply the prelude function `words` on the result.

```
sep :: String -> String -> String
sep _ [] = []
sep s1 (s:ss) | s `elem` s1 = " " ++ sep s1 ss
              | otherwise   =   s : sep s1 ss
```

And then we can ofcourse make it a bit more haskell by binding it together with some high effective haskell functions.

```
sep2 :: String -> String -> [String]
sep2 s1 s2 = words $ map(\x -> if (x `elem` s1) then ' ' else x) s2
```

Comment: This is nice and handy and I appreciate the help and idea, the thing is I can't change my type since it's given already, it needs to stay
`sep :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]`

Comment: @Wireless The type doesn't need to change from what you were given. `String` is `[Char]`, and `[String]` is `[[Char]]`, so `sep2` is already `[Char] -> [Char] -> [[Char]]`, which is a lot like `[a] -> [a] -> [[a]]`, so you can just use a more general type signature (the one you were given).